# How to use inline code with a trailing whitespace?

Tags: whitespace, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

When I use

```
``# ``
```

in my Sphinx documentation I get the following warning:

```
WARNING: Inline literal start-string without end-string.
```

Trying

```
:samp:`# `
```

leads to

```
WARNING: Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
```

The problem seems to be the trailing whitespace however I couldn't figure out a way of getting around this problem. Escaping the whitespace with a backslash (`\`) doesn't help either (for the first example the warning persists and for the second example the whitespace is omitted in the generated docs).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31332035/3767239) doesn't work because the inline code section interprets the `|space|` as a literal string.

---

Experienced with Sphinx 1.6.2.

Comment: I suggest you [submit a bug report to Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/new) and reference this question and the other. I couldn't figure out a workaround either.

Comment: Same here, no luck doing that!

Comment: @StevePiercy Speaking about a bug what would be the expected behavior? Should escaping with a backslash work?

Comment: I would say expected behavior is either should work: (1) escaping a space with a backslash, or (2) a trailing space without escaping. The ensuing discussion may provide a core developer's preference and ultimate decision.

Comment: I would not expect escaping with a backslash to work in inline literals. The Docutils documentation says: "No markup interpretation (including backslash-escape interpretation) is done within inline literals", and also "...the preservation of whitespace cannot be guaranteed. If the preservation of line breaks and/or other whitespace is important, literal blocks should be used". http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-literals.

Comment: After doing some more research I found [this part of the docs](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#inline-markup) (see 3.) to define "The end-string must be immediately preceded by non-whitespace.". So it looks like it's not possible per definition. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31370289/3767239) has introduced a custom role for accomplishing a similar task however it requires modifying the Sphinx code. I'll probably head to github and seek for advice there.

Comment: Although the docutils [Inline markup recognition rules](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#inline-markup-recognition-rules) flat out say "nope" in yet another place, I wonder if creating a Sphinx add-on would allow violation of those rules? One other thought: post-process the output. For example, use `"# STRIP_ME"` as inline markup, then replace "STRIP_ME" with an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `"literal" role`__ with an escaped space after the intended trailing space::

```
:literal:`# \ `
```

__https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/roles.html#literal

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to use a no-break space character (U+00A0) instead of a regular space (U+0020) for the trailing whitespace.

There are several ways to insert a literal no-break space character. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Keyboard_entry_methods.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However I am not sure how I would insert a NBSP in the source. [The documentation](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#unicode) states that unicode directives may only be used in substitution definitions and AFAIK they cannot be used within inline code sections. In addition when I compile my docs to e.g. HTML then this probably ends up as a different HTML entity (which most likely serves the visual purpose however when that piece of code is copied people will end up with a different character than intended; not sure about that though).

Comment: Answer updated. I use Emacs, and `Ctrl-X 8 Space` works well.

Comment: Thanks I managed to insert it and verified it works. It inserts a `&nbsp;` in the compiled HTML source (anyway this might be the only way to have trailing whitespace in HTML?). Could you comment on the copy & paste part, i.e. what happens if someone copies the inline code section from the rendered HTML? Will they end up copying a regular space or a non-break space character? This probably depends on the browser engine (?), I tried with Firefox and Chrome and ended up copying a regular space.

Comment: In Firefox, this seems to be an old bug that was recently reopened: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359303

Comment: I've seen both in various browsers across operating systems. I would not trust copy-pasta from a web browser. Also if you build a PDF or other non-HTML formats, I would expect `&nbsp;` to be preserved in the target format. Visually it may be fine, but in the source code not so much.

Comment: @mzjn So technically it's not the same. The rendered version will end up with a NBSP instead of a regular space. Also I don't like the fact that in the doc's source it looks like a regular space which is forbidden by [the definition of inline literals](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#inline-markup). At least I'd like to be more verbose in the source, i.e. making it clear that this is a non-break space and not a regular space.

Comment: Whether or not it looks like a regular space in the source depends on the editing environment. For example, in Emacs the default visualization of a non-breaking space is an underscore (underline).