# How to include a tuple in a ..class :: signature as default argument?

Tags: python, tuples, python-sphinx, default-arguments

I'm unable to format a tuple as a default argument properly:

```
.. class:: OutputFunc(args=('value',))
```

This is displayed in the HTML output without the tuple parentheses `args='value'`.

If I add backslashes:

```
.. class:: OutputFunc(args=\('value',\))
```

they are rendered: `args=\('value', \),`

Update: I found this in the sphinx docs, probably there is no solution.

> Default values for optional arguments can be given (but if they contain commas, they will confuse the signature parser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to solve this, the problem is particular to using [a singleton tuple literal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) as default argument.

> This is displayed in the HTML output without the tuple parentheses `args='value'`.

Using sphinx-build 3.5.2 with Python 3.9.0 the parentheses do render, only the comma disappears.

```
.. class:: OutputFunc(args=('value',))
```

[image]

One alternative is to use the tuple constructor instead of the literal.

```
.. class:: OutputFunc(args=tuple('value'))
```

[image]

It's worth mentioning the problem only happens when the literal is a singleton.

```
.. class:: OutputFunc(args=('value', 'value2'))
```

[image]

Finally a solution that retains the comma and the parenthesis is using an invisible Unicode character after the comma, in this example I used U+200B ([the zero-with space character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space)). However other characters could be used (credit to @mzjn the idea was taken from [one of his posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45541342).)

```
.. class:: OutputFunc(args=('value', insert U+200B ZWSP character here))
```

[image]

**EDIT:** After OP feedback.

Apparently using older sphinx-build versions adding more parameters will again cause the bug even with the zero-width whitespace. The easiest solution is updating to a recent Sphinx version in which case the above workaround works even if using multiple parameters.

```
.. class:: OutputFunc(args=('value',​), debug=False)
```

[image]

Comment: This seems like a legitimate bug in Sphinx that should be reported as such.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree (searching through GitHub there will probably be a number of them). This are edge cases related with the comma when there's only a whitespace around it, because it serves as a separator and the whitespaces are normally collapsed by docutils. However, this sort of minor bug can take a long time to solve and users searching will probably prefer having a direct hit on Stack Overflow than having to sift through GitHub. (It can take an unreasonable amount of time to work around something so simple.)

Comment: Only the workaround idea with zero-width space is helpful in my situation. It works for me in Sphinx 3.2, so I'm accepting your answer, thanks.  BTW `tuple('value')` is `('v', 'a', 'l', 'u', 'e')`, should be `tuple(['value'])`.

Comment: @bad_coder, I just accepted. Unfortunately I have bad news. It no longer works when other parameters are added. `OutputFunc(args=('value',), debug=False)`

Comment: @VPfB just tried with the new signature and it works perfectly, update to the latest Sphinx version (there were lots of changes bundled in the last update). For example, in the original problem statement you said the parenthesis were missing but with my Sphinx version they resolved well.

Comment: When updating Sphinx take care that it has several dependencies (as you probably noticed when installing) and those packages should also be updated.