# Is a Bullet List With a Long Link Possible in RST Without Warnings?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

I have a long link escaped like this:

```
`Build Azure Devops Agents With Linux cloud-init for Dotnet Development \
[terraform, azure, devops, docker, dotnet, cloud-init]`_

.. _Build Azure Devops Agents With Linux cloud-init for Dotnet Development [terraform, azure, devops, docker, dotnet, cloud-init]: https://codingsoul.org/2022/04/25/build-azure-devops-agents-with-linux-cloud-init-for-dotnet-development/
```

However, if I try to make that link part of a bullet list:

```
- `Build Azure Devops Agents With Linux cloud-init for Dotnet Development \     
[terraform, azure, devops, docker, dotnet, cloud-init]`_

.. _Build Azure Devops Agents With Linux cloud-init for Dotnet Development [terraform, azure, devops, docker, dotnet, cloud-init]: https://codingsoul.org/2022/04/25/build-azure-devops-agents-with-linux-cloud-init-for-dotnet-development/
```

I get the following warning:

```
Inline interpreted text or phrase reference start-string without end-string.
```

I don't know how to parse that warning and the docs / online searches haven't helped me.

Surely bullet lists of long links are a common use case and I'm just missing some obvious documentation somewhere, right?

Here is a bullet list (of long links, coincidentally) I came across in my search that didn't help:

- [How to use inline code with a trailing whitespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45534757/how-to-use-inline-code-with-a-trailing-whitespace)
- https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/3778
- https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#lists-and-quote-like-blocks

Comment: 1. You had a typo of `te3rraform`. 2. You need to add spaces before `[terraform...` as contents of a bullet item must be aligned.

Comment: typo was a copy pasta error I guess, I wasn't having problems with that before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me. You need to indent second and subsequent lines in a list item to align with the first character in the first line.

```
-   `Build Azure Devops Agents With Linux cloud-init for Dotnet Development \
    [te3rraform, azure, devops, docker, dotnet, cloud-init]`_

.. _Build Azure Devops Agents With Linux cloud-init for Dotnet Development [te3rraform, azure, devops, docker, dotnet, cloud-init]: https://codingsoul.org/2022/04/25/build-azure-devops-agents-with-linux-cloud-init-for-dotnet-development/
```

Also your link label also did not match, which generated an error of `ERROR: Unknown target name: "Build Azure Devops Agents With Linux cloud-init for Dotnet Development \ [terraform, azure, devops, docker, dotnet, cloud-init]".`

Comment: Yes, this works. And the line continuation backslash can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks @Steve! The indentation for the bullet was the problem.